# cannot switch to lxde in gnome3

Tags: desktop-environment

I installed lxde on ubuntu gnome: `sudo apt-get install lxde`. But after I logout, I cannot choose LXDE as session. Only default and gnome appear. Did I miss something ?

Comment: The LXDE.desktop xsession file appears to be provided by package `lxde-common` - which doesn't seem to be a dependency of the simple `lxde` package.

Comment: And that should be in `/usr/share/xsessions`. `lxde-common` is a dependency of `lxde` in 16.04 according to `apt show lxde` and so should be installed!

Comment: I restarted gdm and now it works. Interestingly, a reboot did not help.